# How to add mathematically the results of two commands in Linux

Tags: linux, expr

In a Debian Linux shell, I am trying to add the results of two separate commands so that I know the sum of both.

I already tried:

```
echo $(expr $(du -sh /srv/mysql) + $(du -sh /srv/www))
```

and variations of it.

It's returning: expr:

> "syntax error: unexpected argument ‘/srv/mysql’

"

of course I also tried to paraphrase the folders, etc.

Comment: Not the main issue, but please read: [What is wrong with `echo $(stuff)`?](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690)

Comment: Regarding `syntax error: unexpected argument ‘/srv/mysql’` that happens because `du -sh /srv/mysql` returns something like: `500M /srv/mysql` and therefore that's not a correct number.

Comment: Just use `du -csh /srv/www /srv/mysql` to get the `c`umulative disk usage of both directories (which is not the same as the sum of the disk usage of each run in isolation if both directories contain instances of the same file for instance).

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

could be used with any shell (bash, zsh, sh, dash...)

```
echo "$((
    (
        $(du -s /srv/mysql | awk '{print $1}') +
        $(du -s   /srv/www | awk '{print $1}')
    ) / 1024
))MiB"
```

Or simply:

```
du -shc /srv/www /srv/mysql | awk 'END{print $1}'
```

The `-c` act as the `count` operator

Comment: Good choice about `du -s` instead of `du -sh`.  
*To avoid cofusion*: About the `MB` at the end of `echo`, it should not be `M` or `MiB`?. Because if I'm not wrong Linux works with `*bibytes`. For example: if  `du -sh`  shows `323M` it actually means `323MiB` or `323 Mibibytes`.

Comment: Thanks, edited accordingly

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming you are dealing with integers …**

I note that `expr` is considered archaic and obsolete.
It has two main uses, arithmetic and regex matching, both of which are available in most shells.

(By the by, "Debian Linux shell" isn't just one thing; it could be Bash or Dash or indeed whichever shell is chosen when the user is added or changed subsequent.)

For arithmetic, POSIX requires the shell (any shell claiming compliance, including `/bin/sh`) to evaluate $(( *expression* )) according to rules similar to those for integer expressions in the C language, so that `$((1+2*3))` should give 7.

The main problem with the original question was that other information besides the digits were included in the output. The first thing to try should be to ask the program generating those digits not to output anything else. Only if that fails, then filter the output. There are many many ways to do that, but the simplest is just

```
tr -dc 0-9
```

which will remove everything that's not a digit.

**If you need decimal fractions …**

*(decimal fractions are usually fixed point, like 1.23, but floating point systems can understand fixed point numbers as well, so you can use either.)*

Neither `expr` nor `$((…))` can cope with decimal fractions. For that you need `bc` or to use a separate scripting language that has fixed point or floating point built in, such as `awk` or `perl` or `python`.